# Hide ProgressBar widget

Tags: android, progress-bar

I start an Activity1 from my MainActivity using Intent.
Activity1 takes quite a while to load (perhaps the Ads) so to reassure users that my app has not crushed I display a Circular ProgressBar in a linear layout id loading. To do this I turn Visibility of loading to Visible in the onClick event of a button.
Coming back from Activity1 I set visibility to Invisible like this:

```
 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> resultLaunch = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if(result.getResultCode()==111){
                assert result.getData() != null;
                String data= result.getData().getStringExtra("from");
                if(data.equals("activity1")) {
                    loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);// back from Activity1 switch-off 
loading
                    
                }
            }
```

This works well but if user clicks the back button of his phone Progress Bar stays visible forever.
I have tried to set visibility in onResume() of MainActivity but it does not work.
I rather avoid to set up a timer. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);// back from Activity1 switch-off loading
}
```

I turns out to work fine

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because, the result code is not equals to 111. Change 111 with Result.Sucess and it will work fine. If you also want to hide the progress bar even if data is empty, add else statement and set visibility of progress bar to gone in there.